# How to change syntax highlighting of URLs in Visual Studio Code

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

One answer is to just turn off linkifying of URLs altogether:

```
"[html]": {
    "editor.links": false
  },
```

But what I'm trying to do is keep that feature and turn off the actual underlining. (It's because I have a very compact font and line spacing and there isn't room for the underlining without bleeding into the next line!)

I've searched the VSCode theme files and they don't seem to make any mention of URLs or links or any regex involving "http.*" or anything. So where the heck is that syntax highlighting rule defined and how can I tweak it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Stack Overflow post
[Getting rid of underline (link)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69555779/165358),
this advice was given:

> If you want to keep links clickable and just get rid of the
> underlines, I found a way:
>
> open `resources\app\out\vs\workbench\workbench.desktop.main.css`
>
> search for `.monaco-editor .detected-link,` and delete it.
>
> Reopen VSCode, it will show some warning. Allow it and it's done.
>
> After every update, you'll need to edit this file again.

(If this answer helps you, please also upvote the above
Stack Overflow answer.)

Comment: Oh, wow, I was about to conclude that this was impossible, based on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Semantic-Highlighting-Overview

But sure enough, your solution works! I never would've figured that out in a million years. Thank you!

Comment: Update: this turns out to be annoying because VScode warns me that my installation has been "corrupted" and, as you say, every update I have to repeat it. But it does work and I'm grateful!